# How to get bbox coordinates of text on cartopy map

Tags: python, cartography, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm making a map using cartopy in python and am labeling the countries based on the centroid of the country. However, if a name extends outside of the map's crop I would like to move the label so that it's within the map's bounds. There is a photo example below where 'Afghanistan' is outside of the maps crop. I am trying to get the bbox of the label to determine if it's within the bounds or not but am having trouble. I've tried two different ways (and some minor changes within each).

I first tried getting the bbox in points and then converting it to lat/lon using the maps aspect ratio and width but this didn't work.

```
annotation = ax.annotate(text=name_str, xy=name_point, alpha=.3, ha='center', path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=4, foreground="white")])
bbox = annotation.get_window_extent(renderer=fig.canvas.get_renderer())
bbox_width_points = bbox.width
aspect_ratio = ax.get_data_ratio()
map_extent = ax.get_extent()
width_deg_lon = bbox_width_points / aspect_ratio / fig.dpi * (map_extent[1] - map_extent[0])
height_deg_lat = bbox.height / fig.dpi * (map_extent[3] - map_extent[2])
```

I next tried a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69473844/can-you-calculate-the-size-of-a-text-annotation) that also didn't work.

```
annotation = ax.annotate(text=name_str, xy=name_point, alpha=.3, ha='center', path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=4, foreground="white")])
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
bbox = annotation.get_window_extent(renderer=renderer)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Screenshot of a map showing southern asia and how the label 'Afghanistan' is outside of the map's extent]

Comment: Consider providing a minimalistic working code example so people can reproduce the error.